# I'm having issues getting a button by label

Tags: subliminal

I'm having an issue just getting a UIButton by accessibility label.

Here's how I'm setting the accessibility of the UIButton:

```
[_dobblerButton setAccessibilityLabel:@"dobbler_button"];
[_dobblerButton setAccessibilityTraits:UIAccessibilityTraitButton];
[_dobblerButton setIsAccessibilityElement:YES];
```

Here's how I'm trying to get it:

```
_usernameField = [SLButton elementWithAccessibilityLabel:@"dobbler_button"];
[_usernameField logElement];
```

The log call throws an error:

```
Unknown location: Unexpected exception occurred SLUIAElementInvalidException for reason: Element '<SLButton description:"dobbler_button">' does not exist.
```

I've tried using `SLButton elementMatching` to print out all accessibility labels, and dobbler_button definitely shows up.

Let me know if there's anything else I can provide to help debug this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out I had accessibility turned on by the button's containing view. This doesn't work, per [Apple's docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/iPhoneAccessibility/Making_Application_Accessible/Making_Application_Accessible.html)

> if your application displays a custom view that contains other elements with which users interact, you need to make the contained elements separately accessible. At the same time, you need to make sure that the container view itself is not accessible. The reason is that users interact with the contents of the container, not with the container itself.

Comment: I'm glad you found the answer in the docs. I'd also recommend using the [Accessibility Inspector](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/TestingAccessibilityOfiOSApps/TestAccessibilityiniOSSimulatorwithAccessibilityInspector/TestAccessibilityiniOSSimulatorwithAccessibilityInspector.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012619-CH4) to look around your app if you run into issues like this--it will show you how your accessibility labels etc. will actually be read by the system (vs. how they look in the code). In this case you would have seen info about the container but not the button itself.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can achieve this by going to your .storyboard file (or wherever you design the UI) click the button and it should be in one of the menus on the right.

Comment: I will have to look on my Xcode because i dont exactly know off the top of my head, i'll post screenshots

Comment: "**it** should be in one of the menus on the right" What is **it** that I'm looking for? Also, this button is created programmatically. It is not in a nib.

Comment: oh, if it is created programattically then try looking it up here. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/iPhoneAccessibility/Making_Application_Accessible/Making_Application_Accessible.html